# d3js behavior.drag prevents editable content?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, drag

I have a little popup editor used for some data input in a `d3js` application. As this editor sometimes covers the interesting area of the page, I made the popup draggable using `behavior.drag`

This works quite nice... I can now drag the popup. However I cannot edit the content anymore.

Anybody who knows why this does not work, and what to do about it?

Here is a jfiddle of my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ey73b557/41/.
This is the drag behavior from the code:

```
// defined the drag behavior
var editTaskdrag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on("drag", function(d,i) {
          var d3EditTaskObject = d3.select(this);
          d3EditTaskObject.style("left", addPx(d3EditTaskObject.style("left"), d3.event.dx)); 
          d3EditTaskObject.style("top", addPx(d3EditTaskObject.style("top"), d3.event.dy)); 
        })
          ;
```

You can edit the `*edit me` text. Click on the blue button, and a popup appears with the same `*edit me*` text. However, you cannot edit this one. Both elements have `contenteditable` set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict between click and drag, which is well known in D3 codes.

In your case, the simplest solution (certainly not the most elegant one) is just removing the drag behaviour when you click the span:

```
.on("click", function(){
    popupEditor.on(".drag", null)
})
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
// this generates the 'editor' - used for both the static and the draggable version
function simpleEditor(d3Object) {
  d3Object.append("span")
    .text("content: ");
  d3Object.append("span")
    .text(" * edit me * ")
    .attr("contenteditable", "true")
    .style("border", "solid black 1pt")
    .style("background", "lightblue")
    .on("click", function() {
      popupEditor.on(".drag", null)
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      popupEditor.call(editTaskdrag)
    })
}
// arithmetic on strings with px at the end: addPx("110px", 23) = "133px"
function addPx(s, d) {
  var number = parseInt(s, 10); // this really works even if the string is "120px"
  number += d;
  return number.toString() + "px";
}
// defined the drag behavior
var editTaskdrag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    var d3EditTaskObject = d3.select(this);
    d3EditTaskObject.style("left", addPx(d3EditTaskObject.style("left"), d3.event.dx));
    d3EditTaskObject.style("top", addPx(d3EditTaskObject.style("top"), d3.event.dy));
  });
// generate the static editor
simpleEditor(d3.select("#staticEditor"))
  // and now the draggable editor, hidden, but with drag behavior
var popupEditor = d3.select("#popupEditor");
simpleEditor(popupEditor);
popupEditor.attr("hidden", "true")
  .call(editTaskdrag);
// click this button to get the draggable popup. However, it is not editable anymore
d3.select("#button")
  .on("click", function() {
    d3.select("#popupEditor")
      .style("position", "fixed")
      .style("left", "30%")
      .style("top", "30%")
      .style("background", "grey")
      .style("padding", "1em")
      .style("box-shadow", "0.5em 0.5em lightgrey")
      .attr("hidden", null)
  })
```

```css
#button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: solid black 1pt;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 1em
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p id="staticEditor">
  </p>
  <p id="popupEditor">
  </p>
  <p>
    <span id="button">
Click here to open the pop up editor
</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was suspecting something like this, and tried to google for it... maybe used the wrong words. Would you have a good source for information on the click/drag conflict?

Comment: This is a well known issue. Have a look here, for instance: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a84aeb78fea81e1ad806

Comment: Thanks - it worked in the toy example, but it didn't work when including this in my application. Turned out I also needed to set `on("mousedown.drag", null)`. So I wonder is there a generic solution to the problem?